# Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this switch statement (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, hide, show

Hey all, its your typical slider - both automated and controlled by user click. Problem is when you click, if you are on last slide,it shouldn't show right arrow, and if you are on first slide, it shouldn't show left arrow. If you are anywhere else, it should show both arrows. However, when on last slide it still shows right arrow. However, when on first slide, it correctly doens't show left arrow. But then when you get to middle slides, it doesn't bring back right arrow:

```
    $(".paging").show();
$(".image_reel img:first").addClass("active");
$active = $(".image_reel img:first"); 

var imageWidth = $(".window").width();  
var imageSum = $(".image_reel img").size();  
var imageReelWidth = imageWidth * imageSum;

$(".image_reel").css({'width' : imageReelWidth});

rotate = function(){

    var triggerId = $active.attr('src').substring(7,8);
    var image_reelPosition = (triggerId - 1) * imageWidth;



    $(".image_reel img").removeClass("active");
    $active.addClass("active");

    switch ($active.attr('src')) {
        case "images/4.png":
            var $lastPic = $active.attr("src");
            manageControls($lastPic);
            break;
        case "images/1.png":
            var $firstPic = $active.attr('src');
            manageControls($firstPic);
            break;
        case "image/2.png":
            var $standardPic = $active.attr('src');
            manageControls($standardPic);
            break;
        case "image/3.png":
            var $standardPic = $actice.attr('src');
            manageControls($standardPic);
            break;
    } 




    $(".image_reel").animate({
        left: -image_reelPosition
    }, 500);
};

rotateSwitch = function(){
    play = setInterval(function(){
    if(!$(".paging a").show()) $(".paging a").show(); //This is CRITICAL - this makes sure the arrows reappear after they have been removed
        $active = $(".image_reel img.active").parent().next().find("img");
        if ($active.length === 0){
            $active = $('.image_reel img:first');
            var $firstPic = $active.attr("src");
            manageControls($firstPic); 
        }
        rotate();
    }, 5000);
};

rotateSwitch();

$(".paging a").click(function(){
    $active = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightCtr') ? $(".image_reel img.active").parent().next().find('img') : $(".image_reel img.active").parent().prev().find('img');


    if ($active.length === 0){
        $active = $('.image_reel img:first');
    }


    clearInterval(play);  
    rotate();
    rotateSwitch();  


    return false; 
});


manageControls = function(whichImg){
    (whichImg == "images/4.png") ? $(".paging a#rightCtr").hide() : $(".paging a#rightCtr").show();
    (whichImg == "images/1.png") ? $(".paging a#leftCtr").hide() : $(".paging a#rightCtr").show();

    if(whichImg != "images/1.png" || whichImg != "images/4.png"){
        $(".paging a#rightCtr").show();
        $(".paging a#rightCtr").show();
    }

};
```

html:

```
<div class="window">
            <div class="image_reel">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/1.png" alt="" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/2.png" alt="" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/3.png" alt="" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/4.png" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="paging">
            <a href="#" id="leftCtr">Left</a>
            <a href="#" id="rightCtr">Right</a>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks for any response.

Comment: What output do you get from the error console? Also, are "default"s mandatory in javascript switch statements?

Comment: I get no error. All I know is that when I'm on last slide, left arrow doesn't go away and it should based on switch statment. When on first slide, left arrow does go away, but when go on second slide, the left arrow doesn't come back.

Comment: @Stephen no, a `default` case is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `switch` statement is weird, but it's OK I think. I believe that the problem is with that "manageControls" function. Inside the last `if` statement, you do the same thing twice. Also the expression in the `if` will *always* be true.

I said that the `switch` is "weird" because, well, it is:

```
    switch ($active.attr('src')) {
    case "images/4.png":
        var $lastPic = $active.attr("src");
        manageControls($lastPic);
        break;
```

OK.  So for that first `case`, you now know that the "src" attribute of the active element is "images/4.png".  So, if you know that, why do you need to get it again to set the "$lastPic" variable?  Why do you need those variables at all?  Why not just collapse the entire `switch` down to

```
 manageControls($active.attr('src'));
```

Comment: one problem was in the manageControls, it was supposed to be leftctr not rightctr in the second ternary. But also your recommendation actually made it work. For example, with the switch statement, it wouldn't return both buttons when not on first and last slide, but our solution does. Do you know why your does and the switch didn't? Strange, because it seems they were doing same thing.

Comment: It was probably the problem @aularon found.

Answer (score 1):

It is working, you just have a typo:

```
        var $standardPic = $actice.attr('src');
                                ^
```

should be

```
        var $standardPic = $active.attr('src');
```

**Notes:**

- Your code can be rewritten in a much more elegant way, you can use another logic instead of the `switch` statement, especially with the help of `jquery` selectors.
- Use [`firebug`](http://getfirebug.com/), it helps with javascript debugging and web development in general, and it has a console that shows errors.